# Analog audio splitting with sampling

Tags: analog, audio, signal

I want to build an audio visualizer and have the audio passthrough to another audio jack, so I do not have to mess with external splitters.

I have come up with the following schematic:
[image: Sampler with passtrough]

Should I be connecting the outgoing signal directly to the ingoing one instead? Is the signal sufficient to perform FFT on the received data given that the ADC of the ESP has 12bit resolution?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the analogue levels are compatible and, have you double checked which pins on the device accepts an analogue input? Have you established what power supply regime is needed and what decoupling capacitors are required? What is you policy on floating inputs?

Comment: It is unclear what you should do. The output is fine if you want the volume control to affect it. If you don't want that, then don't wire it via volume control. There also is no amplification, so it is unclear what you mean by that. There is no standard amplitudes that would define if you need amplification or attenuation. It depends if that signal is from headphone or line or mic or whatever output. The largest problem still is that the ADC can't read negative voltages so that circuit won't work without biasing the ADC input to mid-supply.

Comment: @Justme thank you. I plan to use the signal provided by a smartphone. I am quite new to electronics so I guess I need to do some research :^)

Comment: @Curunir OK, but what is on the output? If headphones, you sure can expect almost no signal is available through volume control. If an amplifier input, it may work but attenuate somewhat.

Comment: On the output I will have a stereo speaker system connected, no amplifiter in between.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't pass the input directly through to the output, if you want the output to be the same as the input